# How do I parse this xml using linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

So, I need just the value of those equals that are immediately within the `<and>` and not within the `<not>`. So, I need the the following: 7942 and 6252. How do I get these?

```
<aaa>
    <and>
        <equal ident="qwe">7942</equal>
        <equal ident="qwe">6252</equal>
        <not>
            <equal ident="qwe">1056</equal>
        </not>
        <not>
            <equal ident="qwe">6562</equal>
        </not>
    </and>
</aaa>
```

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong, and your query doesn't use `varequal` which is going to make it harder...

Comment: I am just trying to find out what exactly needs to be the linq query, because whatever I was using was incorrect and was not retrieving any value.

Comment: Your XML is not valid - the `<equal>` tag needs to have a matching `</equal>` tag, but you have `</varequal>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either this is a invalid xml, and you cannot parse it with Linq, or you have typo, and opening tag names should match closing tag names, e.g:

```
<aaa>
  <and>
    <equal ident="qwe">7942</equal>
    <equal ident="qwe">6252</equal>
    <not>
      <equal ident="qwe">1056</equal>
    </not>
    <not>
      <equal ident="qwe">6562</equal>
    </not>
  </and>
</aaa>
```

Parsing this xml looks like:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var result = xdoc.Descendants("and").Elements("equal").Select(e => (int)e);
```

Gives:

```
7942
6252
```

Same with XPath

```
var result = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//and/equal").Select(e => (int)e);
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, that was a typo. I have fixed it now.